# Guitar to Hammond tone wheel control interface

Tags: interface

I'm new to electronics, but have been working on tube amps for a long time. I'm attempting to make a controll interface that allows me to control a Hammond tone wheel organ from guitar.Tonewheels are like gears with differing amount of teeth on them to create frequency sine waves via a magnetic pickup, not unlike an industrial tach.The signal is then filtered and amplified. I would like to add transistors to switch the signal paths (36 Tonewheels in all) and use the frequencies from my guitar strings/ pickups to close the corresponding transistors, allowing the signal of the corresponding Tonewheels to be played.
I'll bet there are thousands of ways to accomplish this, but I'm looking for a reasonably simple set of circuits that I can implement. My idea was to use a frequency to voltage converter like the lm2907 chip , but that's as far as my limited knowledge will let me go. I know y'all have a vast amount of experience, and I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Any help is appreciated, and hopefully in lay mans terms. Thanks! JB

Comment: Are you hoping to play polyphonic (multiple notes at a time) or are you happy with monotonic only?

Comment: That's a great project, but I suspect a very complex one. My approach would be to use a Digital Signal Processor (DSP) to detect which guitar strings were played, and then switch the output of the tonewheels. Possibly someone has already done this and made the software available? Do you know that Electroharmonix have a guitar effects pedal called the B9 that produces the sound of a Hammond tonewheel organ? I know that spoils the fun of developing your own circuit but as I said, this project is quite complex.

Comment: Jazznerd, what you want to do is very hard.  it requires a guitar synth like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QM0_kdUSndk

Comment: here's another AXON video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiOl9cG41_k

Answer (score 1):

You will (or may be) surprised to know that the problems of detecting the individual strings from a normal geetar pick-up is problematic. You either need a bank of individual filters set to semi-tones across the full range (that's nearly 3.5 octaves or 58 semitones) or you use a powerful microcontroller.

A good start is to get hold of individual inductive proximity sensors and have one for each string. Now you split the problem into more manageable blocks and what I've done (in the past) is use a high gain clipper for each of the 6 outputs. This gives virtually a square wave output similar to the tone wheel sound. Mix the square waves together and you turn your geetar into an organ (and I've got old tapes to prove that).

If you are intent on using the hammod tone wheel then good luck but, you might be missing just how complex and slow it is to make filters to detect a single frequency on a geetar.

Comment: yeah, polyphonic note detection is a bitch.

Answer (score 1):

[MIDI guitar pickups](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2cYJbcbdalI) already have much of this sorted out for you. You could use the MIDI output to control your keyboard with addition of a MIDI output decoder.

I would recommend you try a MIDI guitar through a Hammond MIDI tone generator and see if you think it's worth pursuing.